# How get local filename in javaScript and save it with variable for using it later on?

Tags: javascript

Get local data file and read it

i found function showName(), but failed to finish

```
<p><input type="file" id="fileInput" onchange="showName()" /></p>
<script>
    function showName(){  
        window.name=document.getElementById('fileInput');
        console.log('Selected file: ' + window.name.files.item(0).name);
        console.log('Selected file: ' + window.name.files.item(0).size);
        console.log('Selected file: ' + window.name.files.item(0).type);
    }   
    function fName(){  
        alert(window.name);
    }
    showName();
    fName();
</script>
```

i expect to save filename for use it later, but nothing i have get.

Comment: @main.c it is called as an onchange handler

Answer (score 0):

You must call `showName()` or `fName()` only after you selected the file.

```js
function showName(field) {
  window.fakepath = field.value;
  window.filename = field.files.item(0).name;

  fName();
}

function fName() {
  alert('filename: ' + window.filename);
  alert('fakepath: ' + window.fakepath);
}
```

```html
<p><input type="file" id="fileInput" onchange="showName(this)" /></p>
```

*By the way, you have an unexpected question mark at function definition.*

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not recommended to store data on window object, especially if it is possible to avoid that. Moreover, you can not overwrite `name` field on window, as it is always a String.

Here is a very similar to your solution, using local variable `fileData`.
Also, it seems that the fName function should be called after input changes, so I added the necessary line also.

```
<p><input type="file" id="fileInput" onchange="showName()" /></p>
<script>
    let fileData;
    function showName(){  
        fileData=document.getElementById('fileInput');
        console.log('Selected file: ' + fileData.files.item(0).name);
        console.log('Selected file: ' + fileData.files.item(0).size);
        console.log('Selected file: ' + fileData.files.item(0).type);
        fName();   /// added this to run fName when input changes
    }   
    function fName(){  
        console.log(fileData);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It makes no sense to call `showName()` or `fName()` before you choose a file (in your case, this will cause an error). Also, you are right about recommendation do not store data on window object, but you defined `fileData` as global variable, what is the equivalent to `window.fileData`.

Comment: I've edited and answer and removed unnecessary `fName` and `showName` calls. What about `fileData` - it will be script-scoped, moreover I've declared it with the `let` keyword.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `let` keyword. It seemed to me that you used `var fileData`.

Answer (score -1):

Access the file input by Dom selector:

```
var selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
```

And then access the attributes like this:

```
var name = selectedFile.name
```